# How is it possible to list all folders that a particular user/group has permissions on?

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server-2003, file-permissions

Is it possible to list all folders/files that a given group has explicit permissions on, for  a machine running Windows Server 2003?  If so, how?  It would be nice to see inherited permissions as well, but I could do with just explicit permissions.

A little background: I'm trying to update groups/permissions on a test server.  One of the groups, `Devs`, wasn't implemented correctly when it was created, and my goal is to remove it from the system.  It has been replaced by `LeadDevelopers`, which has permissions on many — but naturally not all — of the same folders.  I want to make sure that I don't accidentally orphan any folders or cause any other issues when I remove `Devs`.  It did have some admin-level permissions.

EDIT: The answers so far — at least `*cacls` and `AccessEnum` — provide a way to find out which groups/users have permissions on known directories/files.  I actually want the **reverse** of this behavior: I know the group, and I'm looking for the directories/files for which the group has permissions.  Also, as I noted in a comment, the `Devs` group is not itself a member of any other group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no simple tool for this.  I ended up going with a combination of getting a report from [DumpSec](http://www.systemtools.com/somarsoft/?somarsoft.com) and searching for `Devs` with [FINDSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows/87394#87394).

And yes, I know there are dozens of equally good solutions, but those were the tools I was thinking of when I decided to give up the search for a one-step strategy.

Answer (score 1):

[Sysinternals' AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx) might help do what you want.  It will enumerate the permissions on your directories.  It doesn't exactly show whether the permissions are explicit or inherited, but it will show you all directories (and files) whose permissions differ from their parent.  This probably gets you the same information.  It can also enumerate permissions registry keys in the same manner.

You might also be interested in [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) (command line) and [ShareEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897442.aspx) (like AccessEnum for your file shares).

Comment: AccessEnum is probably your best bet (=1), but is still not a silver bullet, unfortunately. For your specific scenario it should help as it will highlight exceptions to the normal inhertiance, where Devs may have been given explicit permissions. Hopefully you are also taking into account nested group membership, so if Devs is a member of AllGeeks, you need to make sure LeadDevs is also in there or is given permissions at the same places as AllGeeks

Comment: @AdamV, fortunately, I know neither `Devs` nor `LeadDevelopers` is a member of another group, but it's definitely a good point to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I found [a forum entry](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/e6a007a3-3481-4962-a1b1-a75be3525c1d) that may help.

Here is an excerpt:

```
if (($args.Count) -eq 2) {
 $dir = $args[0]
 if ((Test-Path $dir) -eq $true) {
  $script:FoldersFound = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $GroupName = $args[1]
  $folders = Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}

  foreach($folder in $folders) {
   $ACL = Get-Acl -Path $folder.FullName
   foreach($ACE in $ACL.access) {
    if (($ACE.IdentityReference) -like "*\$GroupName") {
     if (($ACE.IsInherited) -eq $false) {
      $FoldersFound.Add($folder.FullName) | Out-Null
      break
     }
    }
   }
  }

  $FoldersFound.Sort()
  foreach($folder in $FoldersFound) {
   Write-Host $folder
  }
 }
} else {
 Write-Host "Syntax:" $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name """path""" """Group Name"""
}
```

Save the above code as `<filename>.ps1`, and run it from the PowerShell prompt with two arguments: "Folder path" followed by "group name."

Example: Navigate to the folder where you saved the script, and type the following, where `<filename>` is (obviously) the name you gave the file, and substitute the path and group name with your own:

```
.\<filename>.ps1 "C:\Users" "Administrators"
```

Now mind you, there is no error handling in the script, so it does not take care of access denied errors or too long path names, for example.

Credit goes to [Andreas Hultgren, MCTS, MCITP](http://ahultgren.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [cacls.exe or xcacls.exe or icacls.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) or even [SetACL](http://setacl.sourceforge.net/index.html). These will not only will list the permissions, including inheritance, but will allow you to edit or replace them.

The cacls/xcalcs and icacls aren't great for displaying permissions for a particular user or group but SetACL seems to have that functionality but has a complex though powerful syntax.